# VPN conflicts from using 2 VPNs

Tags: vpn, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

My QA has a problem. They need to test the app, and the database at the same time. To access our app (testing environment), they need to connect to the company VPN through GlobalProtect, and then they have access. To access our database, they need to connect to DB through AWS VPN Client. However, having both connected at the same time on their local machines leads to unpredictable issues like timeouts and disconnections. How do I solve this?

Comment: There should be nothing unpredictable whatsoever. Maybe different results depending on which client connects first, but that’s it. // You just need to make sure the VPN routes do not overlap. If you cannot do that, this cannot work.

Comment: Question – are they accessing the testing database or the production DB? If it's the testing DB, why does it _need_ to be separate from the rest of the testing environment and be behind a different VPN?

Answer (score 0):

> To access our app (testing environment), they need to connect to the company VPN through GlobalProtect, and then they have access. To access our database, they need to connect to DB through AWS VPN Client.

It might be possible to connect *your company network* to the AWS VPC using a site-to-site VPN. (AWS has [built-in support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/VPC_VPN.html) for site-to-site tunnels, as do some other large cloud providers – but even if it did not, a regular VM on the VPC could act as an endpoint for some standard tunnel like IPsec or WireGuard.)

Then, it will be enough for users to connect to the corporate GlobalProtect VPN and they will be able to reach the DB through the company network, if routes are set up correctly and if your firewall rules allow. (Or vice versa – connecting to the AWS Client VPN service would allow them to reach services on the company network, at least in theory.)